# Adding CAAnimation to sublayer in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

I've got a uitableviewcell subclass with an imageView property. Im fetching the image from the web and when i get it, i'd like to crossfade it into the image view.

I've got this CAAnimation code that i was originally using within the view controller to apply this effect. my code looked like this:

```
    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 0.3f;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;
    [self.photoView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:someKey];
```

Now, i'd like to move that code into my UITableViewCell. I've tried applying that animation in various locations but it doesn't seem to be having an affect. I put it in awakeFromNib (the cell is from a nib file) as well as willMoveToSuperview. Any thoughts?

Comment: Your transition doesn't appear to be changing anything on the photo view

Answer (score 0):

David is right, you're not actually changing the contents of the `imageView` in your code.

I just made this subclass of an `UITableViewCell` and added it to a basic iOS Single View application:

```
#import "AnimatedCell.h"

@implementation AnimatedCell {
    BOOL imageWasGrabbed;
}

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style 
    reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        self.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,44);
        self.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"localImage"];
        self.textLabel.text = @"Locally loaded image";
        self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor].CGColor;
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor groupTableViewBackgroundColor];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)grabImage {
    NSString *path = @"http://www.c4ios.com/images/temp/webImage@2x.png";
    NSURL *webImageUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:path];
    NSData *webImageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:webImageUrl];
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:webImageData];

    CATransition *transition = [CATransition animation];
    transition.duration = 1.0f;
    transition.delegate = self;
    NSString *n = kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut;
    transition.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:n];
    transition.type = kCATransitionFade;

    [self.imageView.layer addAnimation:transition forKey:@"animateContents"];

    self.imageView.image = image;
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(!imageWasGrabbed) {
        [self grabImage];
    }
}

-(void)animationDidStop:(CAAnimation *)anim finished:(BOOL)flag {
    self.textLabel.text = @"Web loaded image";
    imageWasGrabbed = YES;
}

@end
```

After you add the transition to your cell's imageView layer, you need to call the following:

```
self.imageView.image = image;
```

For reference, the View Controller for my project looks like this:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "AnimatedCell.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    AnimatedCell *cell = [[AnimatedCell alloc]
                          initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
                          reuseIdentifier:@"AnimatedCell"];
    cell.center = self.view.center;
    [self.view addSubview:cell];
}

@end
```